# How to pass a value from a procedure (SQL Server) to Struts 2 using Entity

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, struts2, ognl

**Here is my Procedure:**

```
create procedure [dbo].[reportlist]
@reportedrestaurant int
as
select reportedrestaurant,count(reportedrestaurant) as numberofreport from Report where reportedrestaurant = @reportedrestaurant  group by reportedrestaurant

GO
```

**Here is my code:**

```
public List reportlist(int reportedrestaurant){
    StoredProcedureQuery squery = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("reportlist");
    squery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("reportedrestaurant", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    squery.setParameter("reportedrestaurant", reportedrestaurant);
    List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>)squery.getResultList();
    return list;    
}
```

**Here is my action:**

```
public String execute() throws Exception {
    ReportedDAO dao = new ReportedDAO();
    list = dao.reportlist(restaurant);
    return "success";
}
```

When i execute, i receive `1` record in the list but when i try to get it, it return a non-Integer value like this: `[Ljava.lang.Object;@7c0e76cd`.

**JSP:**

```
<td style="text-align: center"><s:property value="%{reportedrestaurant}"/></td> <td style="text-align: center"><s:property value="%{numberofreport}"/></td>
```

Is there anything wrong in my code? Any solution to fix it?

Comment: Show the code where you trying to get it.

Comment: <td style="text-align: center"><s:property value="%{reportedrestaurant}"/></td>
                                                            <td style="text-align: center"><s:property value="%{numberofreport}"/></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to fix this to use OGNL expression to find a value in the value stack. It's the place where data should reside like an action. If you use `list` then you can get the values by index. Assumed the getter for the `list` is available

```
<td style="text-align: center"><s:property value="%{list[0][0]}"/></td> <td style="text-align: center"><s:property value="%{list[0][1]}"/></td>
```

Or you can create a getters for  `reportedrestaurant` and `numberofreport`

```
public String getReportedrestaurant(){return String.valueOf(list.get(0)[0]);} 

public int getNumberofreport(){return ((BigInteger)list.get(0)[1]).intValue();}
```

then use it on JSP

```
<td style="text-align: center"><s:property value="%{reportedrestaurant}"/></td> <td style="text-align: center"><s:property value="%{numberofreport}"/></td>
```